# Including local npm libraries

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack, serverless

I am using the serverless framework to develop lambda functions in the aws cloud. Currently, I am running into an issue when including a library that I made. It seems the recommended way to do this is to either:

1) `npm install <path/to/your/lib>`

2) `npm link` and related commands

In the first situation, when using `npm install ../libs`, and include the module using `const Libs = require('libs')` , the package appears to install correctly (it is listed in the package.json). However, on uploading the service to aws or using `sls invoke local -f my-func` the following error is thrown:

```
{ Error: Cannot find module 'libs'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:555:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:482:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:604:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Documents/GitHub/serverless-cloud-functions/dynamodb-stream-handlers/.webpack/service/service-provider-users-archive-stream-handler.js:419:18)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/Documents/GitHub/serverless-cloud-functions/dynamodb-stream-handlers/.webpack/service/service-provider-users-archive-stream-handler.js:20:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Documents/GitHub/serverless-cloud-functions/dynamodb-stream-handlers/.webpack/service/service-provider-users-archive-stream-handler.js:376:16)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/Documents/GitHub/serverless-cloud-functions/dynamodb-stream-handlers/.webpack/service/service-provider-users-archive-stream-handler.js:20:30)
    at Object.defineProperty.value (/Users/Documents/GitHub/serverless-cloud-functions/dynamodb-stream-handlers/.webpack/service/service-provider-users-archive-stream-handler.js:63:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Documents/GitHub/serverless-cloud-functions/dynamodb-stream-handlers/.webpack/service/service-provider-users-archive-stream-handler.js:66:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:660:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:671:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:573:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:513:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:505:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:604:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at AwsInvokeLocal.invokeLocalNodeJs (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/plugins/aws/invokeLocal/index.js:258:33)
    at AwsInvokeLocal.invokeLocal (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/plugins/aws/invokeLocal/index.js:125:19)
    at AwsInvokeLocal.tryCatcher (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:512:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:569:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:614:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:693:18)
    at Async._drainQueue (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:133:16)
    at Async._drainQueues (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:143:10)
    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
    at runCallback (timers.js:773:18)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:734:5)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:711:5) code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
```

Using `npm link` gives similar results as well. I have a hunch that the issue has to do with the fact that I'm using babel and webpack, but I'm not sure.

Here is the contents of my webpack.config.js file:

```
const slsw = require("serverless-webpack");
const nodeExternals = require("webpack-node-externals");

module.exports = {
    entry: slsw.lib.entries,
    target: "node",

    externals: [nodeExternals()],

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: "babel-loader",
                include: __dirname,
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }
        ]
    },

};
```

Including the individual clients, instead of the overall lib seems to have solved the above error, but now I am faced with a new error.
Here is the serverless.yml file:

```
service: instant-response-api

plugins:
  - serverless-webpack
  - serverless-domain-manager
  - serverless-plugin-aws-alerts

custom:
  alerts:
    topics:
      alarm: ${file(./env.yml):${opt:stage}.ADMIN_SNS_TOPIC_ARN}
    alarms:
      - functionErrors

  webpackIncludeModules: true
  customDomain:
    domainName: ${file(./env.yml):${opt:stage}.DOMAIN_NAME}
    basepath: ''
    stage: ${opt:stage}
    createdRoute53Record: true


provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs6.10
  region: us-west-2
  stage: ${opt:stage}
  environment:
    ${file(./env.yml):${opt:stage}}

  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: "Allow"
      Action:
        - dynamodb:DescribeTable
        - dynamodb:Query
        - dynamodb:Scan
        - dynamodb:GetItem
        - dynamodb:PutItem
        - dynamodb:UpdateItem
        - dynamodb:DeleteItem
        - dynamodb:DescribeTable
      Resource: "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-west-2:*:*"
    - Effect: "Allow"
      Action:
        - sns:Publish
        - sns:CreateTopic
      Resource: "arn:aws:sns:*:*:*"

functions:
  create-service-provider-number:
    handler: create-service-provider-number.main
    memorySize: 3008
    timeout: 30
    logRetentionInDays: 30
    events:
      - http:
          path: create-service-provider-number/{serviceProviderId}
          method: post
          cors: true
    alarms:
      - functionErrors

  service-provider-sms-handler:
    handler: service-provider-sms-handler.main
    memorySize: 3008
    timeout: 30
    logRetentionInDays: 30
    events:
      - http:
          path: service-provider-sms-handler/{serviceProviderId}
          method: post
          cors: true
    alarms:
      - functionErrors

  end-user-voice-handler:
    handler: end-user-voice-handler.main
    memorySize: 3008
    timeout: 30
    logRetentionInDays: 30
    events:
      - http:
          path: end-user-voice-handler/{userId}/{propertyId}
          method: post
          cors: true
    alarms:
      - functionErrors

  end-user-sms-handler:
      handler: end-user-sms-handler.main
      memorySize: 3008
      timeout: 30
      logRetentionInDays: 30
      events:
        - http:
            path: end-user-sms-handler/{userId}/{propertyId}
            method: post
            cors: true
      alarms:
        - functionErrors
```

And here is package.json:

```
{
  "name": "instant-response-api",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "aws-sdk": "^2.177.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-3": "^6.24.1",,
    "jest": "^22.4.2",
    "jest-cli": "^22.1.4",,
    "serverless-domain-manager": "^2.1.0",
    "serverless-plugin-aws-alerts": "^1.2.4",
    "serverless-webpack": "^4.2.0",
    "webpack": "^3.10.0",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^1.6.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@google/maps": "^0.4.5",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.26.0",
    "query-string": "^5.0.1",
    "twilioClient": "file:../libs/twilioClient",
    "dynamodbClient": "file:../libs/dynamodbClient",
    "snsClient": "file:../libs/snsClient"
  }
}
```

My new error:

```
    START RequestId: a9962b1d-21dd-11e8-bc1e-35d1e2dcfd8e Version: $LATEST
Syntax error in module 'service-provider-sms-handler': SyntaxError
    async sendSms({to, from, msg}) {
          ^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
END RequestId: a9962b1d-21dd-11e8-bc1e-35d1e2dcfd8e
REPORT RequestId: a9962b1d-21dd-11e8-bc1e-35d1e2dcfd8e  Duration: 5.62 ms   Billed Duration: 100 ms     Memory Size: 3008 MB    Max Memory Used: 22 MB
```

Comment: It looks like webpack did not include your lib. Can you show you webpack config?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I edited the post to show the config file.

Comment: Seems like your serverless packaging config conflicts with your webpack config. Can you show your `serverless.yml` and your `package.json` as well?

Comment: Sure thing. I was looking through the webpack documentation, and to me it seems like that is were the answer lies. However, i've tried whitelisting using the nodeExternals, and it still doesn't seem to do the trick. Now, however, I am able to `sls invoke local` without issue, but when I try to upload to aws, it is saying I have syntax errors, which I had assumed was an issue with babel not transpiling because of the `exclude` parameter of the webpack config.

Comment: Regarding the `SyntaxError`, isn't `async` only available in Node 8+?

Comment: That is correct, however I am using babel to transpile to Node 6. I am not experienced with webpack at all, and think the issue lies in having the webpack exclude the node_modules folder. I am still looking around for how to exclude my modules, but not others. Or if that is even a smart thing to do.